# RequestanimationFrame wont activate, vanilla js

Tags: javascript, animation

I want a second animation to activate when the first animation x and y coordinates reach a certain point in a canvas.

Some variables:

```
var canvas=document.querySelector("#mittCanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var animasjonID;
var kanonID;
var aktiv=false;
```

Function that runs the first animation.

```
animasjonID = requestAnimationFrame(animer);

var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  setTimeout(loop, i * 3000);
}
function loop(){
    array.push(new fiende(0,450,10,"blue"));
}

function animer() { 
  if (array.length === 0) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animasjonID);
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].flytt();
    if (array.length === 0) {
      break
    }
    array[i].tegn();
  }
}


class fiende {
  constructor(x, y, radius, farge) {
    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.farge = farge;
  }

  tegn() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.farge;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  flytt() {
    if (this.x > 300) {
      if (this.y < 360) {
        if (this.y < 210) {
          if (this.y < 55) {
            if (this.y < 10) {
              array.shift();
            } else {
              this.y -= 0.3;
            }
          } else {
            this.x += 0.4;
            this.y -= 0.31;
          }
        } else {
          this.x -= 0.2;
          this.y -= 0.33;
        }
      } else {
        this.x += 0.4;
        this.y -= 0.3;
      }

    } else {
      this.x += 0.5;
    }

    if (avstandtaarn1(array[0]) < 200) {
      if (aktiv === true) {} else {

        //Here is the problem, when the distance is less than 200, it wont start the second 

        //animation
        kanonID = requestAnimationFrame(Kanimer);
        aktiv = true;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Why wont the it trigger the second kanonIDanimation?

Function to calculate distance:

```
function avstandtaarn1(obj1){
  var xAvstand2=Math.pow(obj1.x-275,2);
  var yAvstand2=Math.pow(obj1.y-330,2);
  var avstand=Math.sqrt(xAvstand2+yAvstand2);
  return avstand;
}
```

Second animation, very similar to first

```
function Kanimer() {
  kanon.kflytt();
  kanon.ktegn();
  kanonID = requestAnimationFrame(Kanimer);
}

class kanonkule {
  constructor(kx, ky) {
    this.kx = kx;
    this.ky = ky;
  }

  kflytt() {
    this.kx += 1;
    this.ky += 1;
  }
  
  ktegn() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.kx, this.ky, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

var kanon = new kanonkule(275, 330);
```

Now if i add this line outside of any loops and function

```
 kanonID=requestAnimationFrame(Kanimer);
```

Then the second animation starts immediately, so im certain the problem must be where i highlighted.

Comment: This is beside the point, but always use English words in your code, instead of Norwegian, because you never know who will look at your code in the future ... for example when you post on a site asking for help. :)

Comment: It was just variable names so I assumed it was okay